# Click antd Table Row edit button and display row values in antd Input on a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a modal component that displays both a form component and a table component. The idea is that I would want to click the 'Edit' button of a row in the table and pass the rows record to the form component so it will be displayed and potentially edited. I have my modal container component setup as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Modal, Button, Form } from "antd";
import RecordsTable from "./RecordsTable";
import RecordsForm from "./RecordsForm";

const ModalButton = () => {
  const [selectedRecord, setSelectedRecord] = useState();
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [recordComponentForm] = Form.useForm();

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
        width={"1100px"}
        bodyStyle={{ height: 460 }}
      >
        <RecordsForm
          selectedRecord={selectedRecord}
          recordComponentForm={recordComponentForm}
        />
        <RecordsTable setSelectedRecord={setSelectedRecord} />
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default ModalButton;
```

The Form component looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Input, Checkbox, Button, Form } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";
import { SaveOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const RecordsForm = ({ selectedRecord, recordComponentForm }) => {
  console.log(selectedRecord);
  const title = selectedRecord ? selectedRecord.Title : null;

  return (
    <Form
      name="seasonForm"
      initialValues={{
        Title: title,
      }}
      autoComplete="off"
      layout={"inline"}
      form={recordComponentForm}
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Title"
        name="Title"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Add a Title" }]}
      >
        <Input
          name="Title"
          placeholder="Record Title"
          value={selectedRecord ? selectedRecord.Title : null}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default RecordsForm;
```

and finally the table component like this:

```
import { Table, Tag, Space } from "antd";
import { EditOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const RecordsTable = ({ setSelectedRecord }) => {
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "ID",
      dataIndex: "ID",
      key: "ID",
      width: 150,
    },
    {
      title: "Title",
      dataIndex: "Title",
      key: "Title",
      width: 250,
    },
    {
      title: "Description",
      dataIndex: "Description",
      key: "Description",
      width: 450,
    },
    {
      title: "",
      key: "Actions",
      align: "center",
      render: (record) => {
        return (
          <>
            <EditOutlined
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedRecord(record);
              }}
            />
          </>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  const data = [
    {
      key: "1",
      ID: "1001",
      Title: "Test Title 1",
      Description: "Testing Description 1",
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      ID: "1002",
      Title: "Test Title 2",
      Description: "Testing Description 2",
    },
    {
      key: "3",
      ID: "1003",
      Title: "Test Title 3",
      Description: "Testing Description 3",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={data}
      pagination={{ pageSize: 5 }}
    />
  );
};

export default RecordsTable;
```

When I try clicking on a rows edit button, I can see in the forms **console.log(selectedRecord)** that the selectedRecord is getting there with the correct values:

[image]

However, I cannot get the value to appear in the required Input of the form.
I was hoping someone may be able to identify where I am going wrong and offer a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to figure this one out! I needed to make use of the `Form.setFieldsValue` call. In my case within the useEffect...

```
const RecordsForm = ({ selectedRecord, recordComponentForm }) => {
  console.log(selectedRecord);
  const title = selectedRecord ? selectedRecord.Title : null;

  useEffect(() => {
    recordComponentForm.setFieldsValue({
      Title: selectedRecord ? selectedRecord.Title : null,
    });
  });
```

This seems to have done the trick. Now, when I click on my Edit button, the Title of the input changes to that of the row I selected. I would be interested to hear on feedback on this solution... Are there any reasons to do it any other way?